# Can Octopus Output variable be decalred in form of an array?

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

I am using Octopus for getting my environment ready with all prerequisites. In one of the octopus step I want some varaibles values to be set dynamically for which I have used the octopus output variables.

If I want to declare the output variable in form of an array, its value not getting read in other step where I want to read that.

Below are few code snippets which I have used (Note : both the steps are having inline powershell script code written):

```
    /*Step A code : Set output variable of step code*/
    $market= "RO"  /*Dynamically identify market depends on machine name */
    write-host $market
    Set-OctopusVariable -name "TestResult_Domain_['+%market%+']" -value 
    "DomainNameOfMachine"



    /*Another step code*/
    $market= "RO"  /*Dynamically identify market depends on machine name */
    write-host $market
    $filterDomain = "Octopus.Action[StepA].Output.TestResult_Domain_['$market']"
```